# Problemas al firmar XML "verify.xsl' stopped: Incorrect reference digest value" con C# .NET 6.0 usando System.Security.Cryptography.Xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, firma-digital

desde Colombia les escribo. Estoy tratando de firmar un documento XML en C# .NET 6.0 utilizando la biblioteca `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` siguiendo las instrucciones de la documentación proporcionadas por mi proveedor de servicios. Las instrucciones del proveedor indican que debo realizar una firma digital con el algoritmo RS256 utilizando mi clave privada y verificarla con mi certificado público.

- Firma digital XML Security.
- Serialización Flattened.
- Algoritmo RS256.
- Firma con la llave privada del cliente.
- Verificación con el certificado público.

Según comenta el proveedor como hay muchas formas de firmar un XML con diferentes tecnologías y librerías, entonces no proveen ejemplos de peticiones firmadas y posteriormente cifradas(aun no sé si mi codigo de cifrado está bien, pero como no paso la capa de seguridad el DataPower de firma no he podido validar aún) Este es mi código que he hecho:

```
private void SingXml(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
        {
            X509Certificate certificate = this.Mycertificate();
            X509Certificate2 privateKey = this.PrivateKey();

            XmlElement? elementToReferenceBody = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("soapenv:EnvelopeBody").Item(0) as XmlElement;

            XmlElement? elementToReferenceTimesTamp = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("wsse:timestamp").Item(0) as XmlElement;
                
            SignedXml signedXML = new SignedXml(xmlDocument);

            signedXML.SigningKey = privateKey.GetRSAPrivateKey();

            signedXML.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;

            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = "#" + elementToReferenceBody!.GetAttribute("Id")!;

            Reference reference2 = new Reference();
            reference2.Uri = "#" + elementToReferenceTimesTamp!.GetAttribute("Id");

            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform(inclusiveNamespacesPrefixList: ""));
            reference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform(inclusiveNamespacesPrefixList: "wsse soapenv"));

            Signature XMLSignature = signedXML.Signature;
            XMLSignature.SignedInfo.AddReference(reference);
            XMLSignature.SignedInfo.AddReference(reference2);

            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate, X509IncludeOption.WholeChain));
            keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue(privateKey.GetRSAPrivateKey()));

            XMLSignature.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
            XMLSignature.Id = "SIG-" + Guid.NewGuid();

            signedXML.ComputeSignature();

            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = (XmlElement)XMLSignature.GetXml();

            xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("wsse:Security")
            .Item(0)!.AppendChild(xmlDocument.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        }
```

según he entendido con la libreria System.Security.Cryptography.Xml especificando los Id de los elementos xml que uno quiere firmar se firman los hijos en este caso estoy firmando el timestamp y el body.

este es el xml que me genera al final:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:timestamp Id="TP-8e796c8d-3866-45f7-8907-b81ad4cbeb37">
                <wsse:Created>2023-10-18T18:15:58Z</wsse:Created>
                <wsse:Expires>2023-10-18T18:20:58Z</wsse:Expires>
            </wsse:timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>holaMundo</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
            <Signature Id="SIG-f549ad59-9478-49cf-bf01-a0960d8f534f" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                    <Reference URI="#id-caf894ca-7b1e-48a3-b0a9-421f057dff64">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </Transform>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <DigestValue>LM7CCG4RExBWebIGk/ghiGK/BQ0tQ61wzZflEc+Bnog=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#TP-8e796c8d-3866-45f7-8907-b81ad4cbeb37">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse soapenv" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </Transform>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <DigestValue>vbbf3Dyfk0IhAhMcWXvtHLMCADbXXp5sqv8HxRv7TX8=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>O6yN+R8MvXeiriHkjMAg1xwJfgS/qhL1R6cYgzf/b9ghRNLbhd...</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>MIIC4jCCAcqgAwIBAgIQFBYhmcV...</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:EnvelopeBody Id="id-caf894ca-7b1e-48a3-b0a9-421f057dff64">
        <EncryptedData Id="EN-8c876b17-ba48-4b22-8dfc-af66e82f0067" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <EncryptedKey Id="EK-ce554b0b-54b7-4da0-84b9-92c5a80aeddd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
                    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <KeyName>CN=nombre de la llave</KeyName>
                    </KeyInfo>
                    <CipherData>
                        <CipherValue>XSklQg/yTDgXASk85oXC7eP05JSCg+CZQfFT...</CipherValue>
                    </CipherData>
                    <ReferenceList>
                        <DataReference URI="#EN-8c876b17-ba48-4b22-8dfc-af66e82f0067" />
                    </ReferenceList>
                </EncryptedKey>
            </KeyInfo>
            <CipherData>
                <CipherValue>FTgLErYgra+SNeC5+z1kqkjmsIxCssSZy1YshA6MXxNFRKmCUfZHEb+QUh...</CipherValue>
            </CipherData>
        </EncryptedData>
    </soapenv:EnvelopeBody>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a identificar lo que está causando este error de seguridad en mi código? ¿Hay algo que estoy pasando por alto o implementando incorrectamente en mi firma digital XML?

Cualquier orientación o sugerencia sería muy apreciada. ¡Gracias de antemano!